# Kubernetes in Azure - where is the ConfigMap definition for Ingress Controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

in Azure Kubernetes Service - where is the ConfigMap definition for Ingress Controller?

I got really confused - I installed Ingress with `helm install` which provided me an nginx Ingress **Pod and Service**.

`helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux`

After that I deployed yaml with `kind: Ingress` so I got **ingres**s resource as well.
So where is the ConfigMap definition? As I heard in AKS it is not neccessarly needed to run `kubectl create configmap` but I need to check one setting (mapping between the Port and service:Port).

So should I find configMap with: `get pods, get services or get pods`  or how?
Thanks

Comment: can you provide the helm chart link you used?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia I updated with my helm install command. I run the upgrade as well `helm upgrade nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml --set tcp.9000="default/frontarena-ads-aks-test:9000"`

Comment: you can get the configmaps using `kubectl get cm` or `kubectl get configmaps` but it is not clear what config you want to see?

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia OK I find it with `kubectl configmaps` I found definition within one of the resutls. 
 `data:
  "9000": default/frontarena-ads-aks-test:9000`

So this means I have the proper mapping of the IC port and my service Port.
You can post this as answer and I will update my other question with this finding and can you please assist me on that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190275/kubernetes-ingress-controller-cannot-tcp-connect-from-outside-virtual-machine

Comment: I had a look at your other question I don't have much experience with networking side of things and given it is specific to EKS, Ingress_Reverse_Proxy_DNS_NAME, etc.; unfortunately I don't have a clue. you could try joining the Kubernetes slack community and could get some help there: http://slack.kubernetes.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Configmap` object, you can use one of the below two:

```
kubectl get cm --namespace <ns> <configmap-name>
```

or

```
kubectl get configmap --namespace <ns> <configmap-name>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to check on this I have configured mapping in  `data:   "9000": default/frontarena-ads-aks-test:9000` in my CM and I have it. So please can you assist me on my issue on my question which I posted. I still have the same issue that I cannot connect to my service with Port 9000 outside although it seems to me that everything is properly configured. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190275/kubernetes-ingress-controller-cannot-tcp-connect-from-outside-virtual-machine

Comment: I am going through the other question and will comment there if I can think of anything useful.

Comment: @KrishaChaurasia - on the second question - my `"kubectl get ingress"` shows port 80 why if I have for it my port 9000?             `backend:
              serviceName: frontarena-ads-aks-test
              servicePort: 9000`

Comment: Ingress IP shows the IP that is exposed to the external world which generally exposes `http` (port `80`) or `https` (port `443`), the `Ingress` resource will internally direct traffic based on the ingress rules which seem to be rightly configured at port `9000` in your config,.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know maybe a way how I could capture the error? I tried with `kubectl logs nginx-$POD_NAME` but nothigng pops up there as well when I try to connect..

Comment: hmm, can't really say, you could check the pods IP using `kubectl get pods -o wide` and see the service endpoints obtained by `kubectl describe svc <svc-name>` has the same matching IPs, that would mean your service is setup correctly, I am not sure how to validate if ingress is setup correctly though.

Comment: I checked they do: PodIP of the Pod and Endpoint Of the Service have the same IP... I was more referring to some logs if I am missing some additional logs how I can track them? except of `kubectl logs pod_name`... I suppose it's OK that I define my Service as ClusterIP and on the Ingress Controller level I define it as internal Load Balancer...Thanks in any case...